# Package xkeyval error 'blur' is undefined

Tags: pstricks

I just put up TeXmaker and MikTeX 2.9 in my new computer. Now, I can't compilate old files which were working lately...I got this kind of fatal error, you can see log below.

I try to pass over but when I to compile PS to PDF I get

> MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

What can I do?

> ! Package xkeyval Error: `blur' undefined in families`,pstricks,pst-tools,pst-
>   node,pst-arrow,pst-3d,pstricks-add,pst-plot,pst-func,pst-tree,pst-text,pst-grad
>   ,pst-coil'.
>   See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>   ...
>   l.133 \prv{\vspace*{2cm}}
>   Try typing  to proceed.
>   If that doesn't work, type X  to quit.

Comment: Show a small, complete example.

Comment: `\usepackage{pst-blur}`