# Issue long time of compiling with bclogo env combined with pst-blur

Tags: compiling, bclogo

I have an example with `bclogo` package without `\usepackage{pst-blur}` the file produce error

```
Package xkeyval Error: `blur' undefined in families `,pstricks,pst-grad,pst-n
ode,pst-coil'
```

A comment from this question [Package xkeyval error 'blur' is undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473607/package-xkeyval-error-blur-is-undefined) suggests to add `pst-blur` package, I followed the proposal and  I got in trouble with a long compilation time

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}
test
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

I get repetetive warnings in the terminal

```
%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY
```

**log file**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.5.17)  21 MAY 2023 20:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test6
(./test6.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-15>
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bclogo/bclogo.sty
Package: bclogo 2016/01/10 v3.1

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count189
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 107.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2022/09/22 v5.0n Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
\bc@invboxh=\skip50
\bc@invboxd=\skip51
\bc@titleLength=\skip52
\logowidth=\skip53

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2022/19/23 v0.72 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 227.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count190
\pstFP@xia=\count191
\pstFP@xib=\count192
\pstFP@xfa=\count193
\pstFP@xfb=\count194
\pstFP@rega=\count195
\pstFP@regb=\count196
\pstFP@regs=\count197
\pstFP@times=\count198
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks18
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen143
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen144
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.co
de.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@xb=\dimen147
\pgf@xc=\dimen148
\pgf@y=\dimen149
\pgf@ya=\dimen150
\pgf@yb=\dimen151
\pgf@yc=\dimen152
\c@pgf@counta=\count199
\c@pgf@countb=\count266
\c@pgf@countc=\count267
\c@pgf@countd=\count268
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen153
\pgfmath@count=\count269
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270
)))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen154
\pgffor@skip=\dimen155
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
\psLoopIndex=\count271

`PSTricks' v3.19  <2023/04/30> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen156
\pst@dimb=\dimen157
\pst@dimc=\dimen158
\pst@dimd=\dimen159
\pst@dimg=\dimen160
\pst@dimh=\dimen161
\pst@dimm=\dimen162
\pst@dimn=\dimen163
\pst@dimo=\dimen164
\pst@dimp=\dimen165
\pst@hbox=\box53
\pst@ibox=\box54
\pst@boxg=\box55
\pst@cnta=\count272
\pst@cntb=\count273
\pst@cntc=\count274
\pst@cntd=\count275
\pst@cntg=\count276
\pst@cnth=\count277
\pst@cntm=\count278
\pst@cntn=\count279
\pst@cnto=\count280
\pst@cntp=\count281
\@zero=\count282
\pst@toks=\toks27
--- We are running latex or xelatex ---
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-color.tex)
\psunit=\dimen166
\psxunit=\dimen167
\psyunit=\dimen168
\pst@C@@rType=\count283
\pslinewidth=\dimen169
\psk@startLW=\dimen170
\psk@endLW=\dimen171

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-arrows.tex
\pshooklength=\dimen172
\pshookwidth=\dimen173
)
\pst@customdefs=\toks28

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-dots.tex)
\pslinearc=\dimen174
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen175
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen176
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen177
\everypsbox=\toks29
\psframesep=\dimen178
\pslabelsep=\dimen179
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen180
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen181
\pst@shift=\dimen182
\ps@imagectr=\count284

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for LaTeX+dvipdfmx
)))
File: pstricks.tex 2023/04/30 v3.19 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
File: pst-fp.tex 2020/11/20 v0.06 `PST-fp' (hv)

>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-grad/pst-grad.sty
Package: pst-grad 2004/07/15 package wrapper for pst-grad.tex (hv)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-grad/pst-grad.tex
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv))
File: pst-grad.tex 2006/11/27 1.06 `pst-grad' (tvz)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-coil/pst-coil.sty
Package: pst-coil 2010/02/01 package wrapper for pst-coil.tex (hv)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-coil/pst-coil.tex
 v1.06, 2006/11/27
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.43, 2022/01/31
\psrow=\count285
\pscol=\count286
\psmatrixcnt=\count287
\psrowsep=\skip54
\pscolsep=\skip55
\pst@args=\count288
\num@pts=\count289
\pst@argcnt=\count290
))
File: pst-coil.tex 2015/05/13 v1.07 `PST-coil' (tvz,hv)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
Package: mdframed 2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-05-15 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count291
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count292
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count293
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count294
))
Package: xparse 2023-02-02 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count295
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
Package: zref-abspage 2022-04-07 v2.34 Module abspage for zref (HO)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty
Package: zref-base 2022-04-07 v2.34 Module base for zref (HO)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
Package zref Info: New property list: main on input line 767.
Package zref Info: New property: default on input line 768.
Package zref Info: New property: page on input line 769.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\c@abspage=\count296
Package zref Info: New property: abspage on input line 65.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty
Package: needspace 2010/09/12 v1.3d reserve vertical space
)
\mdf@templength=\skip56
\c@mdf@globalstyle@cnt=\count297
\mdf@skipabove@length=\skip57
\mdf@skipbelow@length=\skip58
\mdf@leftmargin@length=\skip59
\mdf@rightmargin@length=\skip60
\mdf@innerleftmargin@length=\skip61
\mdf@innerrightmargin@length=\skip62
\mdf@innertopmargin@length=\skip63
\mdf@innerbottommargin@length=\skip64
\mdf@splittopskip@length=\skip65
\mdf@splitbottomskip@length=\skip66
\mdf@outermargin@length=\skip67
\mdf@innermargin@length=\skip68
\mdf@linewidth@length=\skip69
\mdf@innerlinewidth@length=\skip70
\mdf@middlelinewidth@length=\skip71
\mdf@outerlinewidth@length=\skip72
\mdf@roundcorner@length=\skip73
\mdf@footenotedistance@length=\skip74
\mdf@userdefinedwidth@length=\skip75
\mdf@needspace@length=\skip76
\mdf@frametitleaboveskip@length=\skip77
\mdf@frametitlebelowskip@length=\skip78
\mdf@frametitlerulewidth@length=\skip79
\mdf@frametitleleftmargin@length=\skip80
\mdf@frametitlerightmargin@length=\skip81
\mdf@shadowsize@length=\skip82
\mdf@extratopheight@length=\skip83
\mdf@subtitleabovelinewidth@length=\skip84
\mdf@subtitlebelowlinewidth@length=\skip85
\mdf@subtitleaboveskip@length=\skip86
\mdf@subtitlebelowskip@length=\skip87
\mdf@subtitleinneraboveskip@length=\skip88
\mdf@subtitleinnerbelowskip@length=\skip89
\mdf@subsubtitleabovelinewidth@length=\skip90
\mdf@subsubtitlebelowlinewidth@length=\skip91
\mdf@subsubtitleaboveskip@length=\skip92
\mdf@subsubtitlebelowskip@length=\skip93
\mdf@subsubtitleinneraboveskip@length=\skip94
\mdf@subsubtitleinnerbelowskip@length=\skip95

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-node/pst-node.sty
Package: pst-node 2012/09/18 v1.01 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-node' (HV)
Package: pst-node 2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex)
File: pst-node.tex 2015/05/13 1.07 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-2.mdf
File: md-frame-2.mdf 2013/07/01\ 1.9b: md-frame-2
)
\mdf@frametitlebox=\box57
\mdf@footnotebox=\box58
\mdf@splitbox@one=\box59
\mdf@splitbox@two=\box60
\mdf@splitbox@save=\box61
\mdfsplitboxwidth=\skip96
\mdfsplitboxtotalwidth=\skip97
\mdfsplitboxheight=\skip98
\mdfsplitboxdepth=\skip99
\mdfsplitboxtotalheight=\skip100
\mdfframetitleboxwidth=\skip101
\mdfframetitleboxtotalwidth=\skip102
\mdfframetitleboxheight=\skip103
\mdfframetitleboxdepth=\skip104
\mdfframetitleboxtotalheight=\skip105
\mdffootnoteboxwidth=\skip106
\mdffootnoteboxtotalwidth=\skip107
\mdffootnoteboxheight=\skip108
\mdffootnoteboxdepth=\skip109
\mdffootnoteboxtotalheight=\skip110
\mdftotallinewidth=\skip111
\mdfboundingboxwidth=\skip112
\mdfboundingboxtotalwidth=\skip113
\mdfboundingboxheight=\skip114
\mdfboundingboxdepth=\skip115
\mdfboundingboxtotalheight=\skip116
\mdf@freevspace@length=\skip117
\mdf@horizontalwidthofbox@length=\skip118
\mdf@verticalmarginwhole@length=\skip119
\mdf@horizontalspaceofbox=\skip120
\mdfsubtitleheight=\skip121
\mdfsubsubtitleheight=\skip122
\c@mdfcountframes=\count298

****** mdframed patching \endmdf@trivlist

****** -- success******

\mdf@envdepth=\count299
\c@mdf@env@i=\count300
\c@mdf@env@ii=\count301
\c@mdf@zref@counter=\count302
Package zref Info: New property: mdf@pagevalue on input line 895.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 164 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 164 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 201 replaced by U+FFFD.
\c@bclogocompteur=\count303
\bcval@epBarre=\skip123
\bcval@framesep=\skip124
\bcval@tailleOndu=\skip125
\bcval@borderWidth=\skip126
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 216 replaced by U+FFFD.
\bcval@margeG=\skip127
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 217 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 217 replaced by U+FFFD.
\bcval@margeD=\skip128
\bc@envbox=\box62
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 334 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 454 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 454 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 454 replaced by U+FFFD.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-blur/pst-blur.sty
Package: pst-blur 2005/09/08 package wrapper for pst-blur.tex (hv)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-blur/pst-blur.tex
 v2.0, 2005/09/08)
File: pst-blur.tex 2005/09/08 v2.0 `PST-blur' (hv)
) (./test6.aux)
\openout1 = `test6.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5
.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2022/07/10 v2.5l Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 8.
File: bc-fleur.mps Graphic file (type mps)
<bc-fleur.mps>
Package mdframed Info: Not enough space on this page on input line 9.
 [1

] (./test6.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11611 strings out of 478267
 216818 string characters out of 5839314
 1846476 words of memory out of 5000000
 31498 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512319 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 319 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 90i,9n,91p,639b,996s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

 Output written on test6.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: use `lualatex`  instead of `xelatex`.

Comment: @user187802 thanks  for the reply, I need to use xelatex

Comment: Is using `tcolorbox` instead of `bclogo` and option?

Comment: @UdiFogiel  No, what I just want is is there tricks to reduce compiling time In the case of this example of  bclogo package (pstricks) with xelatex engine

Comment: with what command are you compiling? try with `xelatex  -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q" foo.tex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile with `xelatex-unsafe` in order to work around the issue with Ghostscript and transparencies.

Here's the console output:

```
> xelatex-unsafe bouxe
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bouxe.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-15>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bclogo/bclogo.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
`PSTricks' v3.19  <2023/04/30> (tvz,hv)
--- We are running latex or xelatex ---
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-color.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-arrows.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-dots.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for LaTeX+dvipdfmx
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-grad/pst-grad.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-grad/pst-grad.tex
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-coil/pst-coil.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-coil/pst-coil.tex
 v1.06, 2006/11/27
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.43, 2022/01/31)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-node/pst-node.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-2.mdf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-blur/pst-blur.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-blur/pst-blur.tex
 v2.0, 2005/09/08)) (./bouxe.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./bouxe.aux)
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on bouxe.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on bouxe.log.
```

Answer (score 1):

in the directory

```
/.../texmf-dist/dvipdfmx
```

you have two files

```
 -rw-r--r--   1 voss  staff   994 21 Nov  2021 dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg
 -rw-r--r--   1 voss  staff  8685 20 Mär 13:19 dvipdfmx.cfg
```

the "unsafe" file has only one important line. If you replace the one
of `dvipdfmx.cfg` with the one from `dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg` then you do not need the special argument in the comment from @Udi Fogiel and you can call xelatex as usual. However, if `dvipdfmx.cfg` will be updated by the system you have to do the changes again.